# Three dots in javascript code

Tags: javascript, firebug

I just found this bit of code within a .js file which is online, live and functional:

```
if (p.length > 0) { l() ...try { I = $.parseJSON(k.getData()); /*and so on until*/ } catch { /*more code*/ }
```

I have never seen three dots as a code element before (I double-checked there weren't quotes anywhere around), but this seems to work: there is no error log in the console. What exactly does this syntax achieve?

Comment: this seems incomplete...

Comment: That's a syntax error for sure (specifically `Unexpected token .`) Are you sure this code is loading and executing? Because that that does not seem possible.

Comment: Added a bit more just to illustrate that it should be irrelevant.

Comment: This looks more like a line print from an IDE or something... `[and so on until]` is not valid JS either.

Comment: Are you viewing the actual JS file?  If you're viewing the script in some sort of browser plugin, maybe it's being truncated.

Comment: Voted to close, this isn't answerable because your assumption is fundamentally incorrect. This *is* invalid syntax: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`.

Comment: @Tim Ha, thanks. Didn't know Firebug did that kind of thing. Case closed.

Comment: You *really* think `[more code]` is valid JS?

Comment: No, I added that myself for illustration purposes. Suggestion for the future: Don't make something else an issue when a specific question is asked.

Comment: Also, there is [Spread Attributes notation](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81#whats-with-the-weird--notation) in JSX (ReactJs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to Tim Goodman: Firebug truncated the js file for some reason and randomly inserted "..." instead.

Answer (score 14):

Just for completeness, ES6 will likely have "..." in it, for "rest" parameters (a replacement for using `arguments`):

```
function g(i, j, ...r)
```

But that is not what this code is doing.

http://espadrine.github.io/New-In-A-Spec/es6/